VBA in word to insert various informations
enter image description hereIn my work, I have an application that generates Word files from a database. Those files are impossible to work with and I have to generate several ones a day, then manually edit them all. So I'm making a macro for me and my coworkers to automatically make the changes we need.
A typical document is as depicted by the picture I attached.
I have a code that allow me to take one info from the list of participants, or several but on the same paragraph, and insert it later with an interpretation, but I need to take various info from each person, from different paragraphs: ex if they are citizen AND present AND alone or with assistance.
It that feasible ?
Sub Compa()

    Dim objDoc              As Document
    Dim rgSignetA           As Range
    Dim rgSignetB           As Range
    Dim objPara             As Paragraph
    Dim strTitre            As String
    Dim strValeur           As String
    Dim strInterpretation   As String
    Dim strResultat         As String
    Dim rgInsertionPoint    As Range
    Dim strTxtParagrahe     As String
    
    On Error GoTo erreur
    Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set rgSignetA = objDoc.Bookmarks("P").Range
    Set rgSignetB = objDoc.Bookmarks("D").Range
    
    strResultat = ""
    
    For Each objPara In objDoc.Paragraphs
        If objPara.Range.Start >= rgSignetP.Start And objPara.Range.End <= rgSignetB.End Then
            strTxtParagrahe = Left(objPara.Range.Text, Len(objPara.Range.Text) - 1)  '  Trim(objPara.Range.Text)
            If strTxtParagrahe <> "" Then ' Ignorer les paragraphes vides
                If objPara.Range.Font.Bold = True And objPara.Range.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle Then ' C'est un "strTitre"
                    strTitre = strTxtParagrahe
                Else ' C'est une "strValeur"
                    strValeur = strTxtParagrahe
                    strInterpretation = ""
                    
                    'Present
                    If InStr(1, strValeur, "Present", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                        strInterpretation = "was present"
                    
                    'Present with translator in the same line
                    ElseIf InStr(1, strValeur, "present", vbTextCompare) > 0 And InStr(1, strValeur, "translator", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                        strInterpretation = "present with translator." & vbCr
                    
                    'and so on
                    End If

                    If strInterpretation <> "" Then
                        strResultat = strResultat & strTitre & " and " & strInterpretation & vbCrLf
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next objPara
    
    ' Définir le point d'insertion après le paragraphe suivant le signet B
    Set rgInsertionPoint = rgSignetB.Paragraphs.Last.Range
    rgInsertionPoint.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    rgInsertionPoint.InsertAfter vbCrLf & strResultat
fin:
    Set rgInsertionPoint = Nothing
    Set rgSignetA = Nothing
    Set rgSignetB = Nothing
    Set objDoc = Nothing
    Exit Sub
erreur:
    MsgBox "Erreur : " & Err.Description & "(" & Err.Number & ")", vbCritical, "Compa"
    
 End Sub


There's no screenshot?

I added it, don't know why it wasn't send the first time...

Are you familiar with Word's Mail Merge features?
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-use-the-mail-merge-feature-in-word-to-create-and-to-print-form-letters-that-use-the-data-from-an-excel-worksheet-d8709e29-c106-2348-7e38-13eecc338679
From your screen shot, it looks like most, or perhaps all, of your information can be inserted directly from the database using mail merge.

Unfortunately I don't have access to the database. I can only generate pre-made document for each case I'm working on, and can only modify the generated document...
